# Sinatra and computed view name

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm completely new in Ruby and Sinatra so please forgive the trivial question:

I wanted to compute the view name instead of just passing in a symbol. I wanted the same action to return different views depending on the current state. There's like 20 different states so putting a good naming convention allows me to express the view name as a string very easily:

```
get "/page" do
  erb "page-#{session[:page]}"
end
```

When I do that all I get is the string instead of the rendered view. Can anyone explain to me how I could do that in Sinatra?

Comment: `sessoion`? That doesn't look right...

Comment: That was just a typo - I don't have the typo in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say you're probably looking for `String#to_sym`. I didn't test now, but all the examples say `erb` receives a symbol argument, not a string - so try this:

```
erb "page-#{session[:page]}".to_sym
```

or equivalently

```
erb :"page-#{session[:page]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass string to `erb` it tries to render that string directly, not seeking for view with corresponding name. Converting string to symbol will help.